# Does httproxy vulnerability apply to Elixir apps?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

Should I reset Proxy header for an Elixir / Phoenix app that uses nginx proxy (s. https://www.nginx.com/blog/mitigating-the-httpoxy-vulnerability-with-nginx/ ) or is the platform not affected?

Comment: I believe the erlang's http server was affected somehow but I didn't dive into details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cowboy doesn't use cgi so this doesn't apply.

Also if you don't use http libraries to call into underlying services, then this wouldn't apply. And if you *do* and those http libraries don't use an `HTTP_PROXY` environment var to set a proxy, then you're fine. Hackney (which is what HttPoison is based on) doesn't appear to do that, you would need to set up a proxy by calling the `connect_proxy/5` function

The docs say...

```
Transport = hackney_tcp_transport,
Host = << "https://friendpaste.com" >>,
Port = 443,
Options = [],
{ok, ConnRef} = hackney:connect(Transport, Host, Port, Options)
```

`To create a connection that will use an HTTP proxy use hackney_http_proxy:connect_proxy/5 instead.`

Comment: So pretty much "probably doesn't apply", that's what I thought, thanks. Though I'll approach that from the other side and will set proxy_set_header Proxy ""; in nginx - if no lib use it, all good and if by any chance one does - all the better.